# Create a python dictionary using a pandas index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have a dataframe where ids is the index of the dataframe and column named target.

```
                 target
ids                                                           
2453453  [-0.047055457]
3534533  [-0.244350435]
6445333  [0.1885366494]
8998292  [0.1285366494]
2323433  [0.5685366494]
...                 ...
```

I want to create a dictionary using this dataframe's index as the key and the row number as value like

```
{
 2453453 : 1, 
 3534533 : 2, 
 6445333 : 3, 
 8998292 : 4, 
 2323433 : 5
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Those row numbers don't appear to have anything to do with the rest of the data, from what you're showing it just looks like an enumeration, so... get the list of `ids`, then [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) them?

Comment: its just the row number in the dataframe as the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) :

```
d = dict(zip(df.index, df.reset_index().index+1))
#{2453453: 1, 3534533: 2, 6445333: 3, 8998292: 4, 2323433: 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new column and call `to_dict` on that column:

```py
df.assign(new=range(1, len(df)+1))['new'].to_dict()
```

but it's easier to just create a dict where the keys are the indices.

```py
dict(zip(df.index, range(1, len(df)+1)))
# or
{k:v for v, k in enumerate(df.index, 1)}
```

Either way, the output is

```
{2453453: 1, 3534533: 2, 6445333: 3, 8998292: 4, 2323433: 5}
```